# Intel 8260 does not work in Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, intel, iwlwifi

I am brand new to the Linux community, and I have installed Ubuntu 14.04. However, I am having some issues with Wifi. Ubuntu does not recognize Wifi at all, and I think it might be a communication problem between the hardware and Ubuntu. I am using a brand new Lenovo Y700 with an intel Core i7 processor.

When I search in terminal for network hardware it recognizes the Intel Wireless 8260 wireless card, but says that it is unclaimed.

```
lshw -class network

  *-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   version: 3a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:94100000-94101fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 15
   serial: 50:7b:9d:5f:1e:82
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:24 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94004000-94004fff memory:94000000-94003fff
```

and searching the network interface configuration does not show a WLAN device.

```
sudo ifconfig -a

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:7b:9d:5f:1e:82  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)
```

also, there is no information listed for a wireless card in `rfkill`

```
rfkill list all

0: hci0: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
```

Here is the result of `uname -r`

```
3.19.0-25-generic
```

I have also attempted to add the proprietary internet drivers by going to `System Settings -> Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers`, and no proprietary drivers appear. I have searched in a number of places, but cannot find a solution that works.

How can I get Ubuntu to recognize that there is a wireless card in my computer? A hitch in my giddyup is that I do not have access to ethernet so am unable to just try adding different packages and installations easily.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Could it be that I am having issues because this is a newer computer? or because it is designed for gaming? or just because I am new to Linux?

Thanks for any information, and please let me know any other information you'd like posted.

Paul

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. So what do you want to fix first, wireless or wired connection? Choose one and [edit] your question respectively.

Comment: Thanks, Pilot. I've edited to just focus on Wifi for now. However, I don't have ethernet, so can't use many of the suggestions that are on other forums.

Comment: OK. We can fix the ethernet later. Please edit your question and add output of `uname -r` terminal command.

Comment: Hold on, I will check what exactly this kernel does support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 with kernel 3.19.

The problem is that the kernel 3.19 does support `Intel 8260`, but it needs firmware that is not in the original `linux-firmware` file.

It is even worse. This kernel supports firmware version 9-12 for this adapter, but the `trusty-updates` package has version 13.

Since you just did a fresh install, I suggest to download and install Ubuntu 14.04.4, that does support the wireless adapter.

Ubuntu 14.04.4 will install kernel 4.2 that supports firmware version 10-15 and you will get firmware v. 13 out-of-the-box.

That will be much easier than to upgrade the kernel without any internet access.

Hopefully your Ethernet adapter will work too. If this is not the case, you can ask another question regarding the Ethernet.

For Lenovo Yoga 700 the wireles adapter is blocked by `ideapad_laptop` kernel module. You can temporarily fix it by running

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
```

This issue has been fixed in the last kernel update since 4.2.0-28. After you install the system and update the kernel, your wireless adapter should work.

Do not forget to install updates for your system and you will not need to stop `ideapad_laptop` any more.

Comment: Thanks, Pilot. I believe it was 14.04.3, and the `uname -r` result is now shown in the question: 3.19.0-25-generic. I have a live USB of 14.04.4 at home, so I will try reinstalling that tonight. Do I have to wipe out the partition before reinstalling? I tried installing 15.10 last night, but it kept booting into the grub2 screen when I selected 'Install Ubuntu' while booting from the USB.

Comment: I will expand the question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Pilot. I will try this tonight and let you know the result.

Comment: It might be worth trying to rename the firmware file to make the module think it is a -12.ucode

Comment: That may be a good idea, but I am not sure there is one.

Comment: @ pilot6  Something like `sudo cp /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-12.ucode` followed by a reboot may work

Comment: I tried wiping out the Ubuntu partition on my hard drive and reinstalling 14.04.4 last night. However, I cannot get grub to go away, except that now it just goes to a black, 'command-prompt-like' screen where the prompt is `[grub]`. I tried booting a Windows Recovery Drive and using `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` but that didn't do anything. When I try to reinstall either Ubuntu 14.04.4 or 15.10 the computer just freezes up on the purple screen that says Ubuntu with 5 dots. Thoughts? Should I post another question regarding this issue now?

Comment: Right, it is better to post another question with some details. But read first http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Update on this (the original question). I figured out that UEFI and secure boot was a main problem with the reinstallation, so I disabled those. Now when I 'Try Ubuntu Before Installing' the wireless still doesn't work, but `lshw -C network` says that the wifi network is DISABLED, instead of UNCLAIMED shown in the original question.  The network icon in the upper right also states that the hardware switch is turned off or disabled, but there is no hardware switch on my computer. Any advice?

Comment: What does `rfkill list` show and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`. Add it to your question. I suggest installing it first. Then we will work that out.

Comment: Running `sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop` should unblock it.

Comment: Thanks, Pilot. I will try installing this again tonight. I'd like to be connected to internet while installing. The university I work at does not give out ethernet access easily and their Wifi system is weird, so easiest for me to do it at home. I will then try your suggestions and report back.

Comment: You can get it work with that command. Or just install, then run the command and install updates.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu 14.04.4 and entering `sudo mod probe -r ideapad_laptop` worked great. Thanks for your help, Pilot.

Comment: As stated the above command works great, but I have to enter it every time I boot into my computer. How can I automate this so that the action is just performed when I boot? I've tried creating a `.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` with `blacklist ideapad-laptop` in it, but that is not working. Other suggestions?

Comment: Do you have kernel 4.2 installed? Then you do not need this command any more. Secondly, you need to use underscore, bit not dash there "blacklist ideapad_laptop"

Comment: Yes, I have 4.2.0-30-generic installed. I also tried the the file with "blacklist ideapad_laptop" and no luck. Is there another step that I am missing?

Comment: That's weird. Yoga 700 has been added to quirk list. But it depends on the model. Yours can be added too, but you need to report it to launchpad and provide some info. Blacklist should work.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a protocol or standard for adding to the quirk list?

Comment: You need to report it to launchpad by running `ubuntu-bug linux`. But you need to enable `idapad_laptop` first. If you drop a link to that bug report, I will look at it.